# Android: OvalShape Drawable clipped at edges

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to create a `OvalShape` `Drawable` with border. To give it an elevated effect, I'm adding shadows around the border.

Relevant code:

```
class Badge extends ShapeDrawable{

void Badge(){
    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderThickness);
    borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    borderPaint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Rect r = getBounds();


    // draw border if needed
    if (borderThickness > 0) {
        drawBorder(canvas);
    }

    int count = canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(r.left, r.top);

    // draw text inside badge
    int width = this.width < 0 ? r.width() : this.width;
    int height = this.height < 0 ? r.height() : this.height;
    int fontSize = this.fontSize < 0 ? (Math.min(width, height) / 2) : this.fontSize;
    textPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
    canvas.drawText(text, width / 2, height / 2 - textBounds.exactCenterY(), textPaint);

    canvas.restoreToCount(count);

}

private void drawBorder(Canvas canvas) {
    RectF rect = new RectF(getBounds());
    rect.inset(borderThickness / 2, borderThickness / 2);
    canvas.drawOval(rect, borderPaint);
    }
}
```

However, the border drawn is clipped at the edges as you can see in the image. Also as the size of the drawable decreases, the edges gets clipped more.

[image: Clipped Edges]

What modification should I do in the code to achieve a perfect circle?

Comment: It doesn't seem to fit your canvas, have you tried to scale your oval little?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit: I tried fiddling with rect.inset(). How do I do the scaling?

Comment: I cannot try this right now, but can you add clipChildren="false" and android:clipToPadding="false" to the layout that contains your shape plus any other layout that contains your layout and has the same size.

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it had no effect.